# Will Django process inclusion tag if I hide it in html template using css

Tags: python, css, django

I am using inclusion tag in sidebar of html page. If I hide the sidebar using css for mobile view. Will Django process the inclusion tag in backend when visited from mobile

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will process and include it. But if your css hides it it wont be displayed.

You can use developer tools (Inspect) in your browser to see the included code.

Comment: Is there anyway to not process it when visited from mobile. Because I don't want to show sidebar and process inclusion tag in mobile view

Answer (score 0):

The {display: none}; CSS property, commands the browser not to render the referenced element, however, the element is acknowledged and processed by the system.

Therefore,yes Django will process inclusion tags even if they are hidden using the {display:none}; property.

To use the property:

Firstly, identify the HTML/class of the element you wish to hide.

If you'd like to hide an element by HTML ID use:#html-id {display:none};

If you'd like to hide a CSS class use: .class-name {display:none};

If you are not sure how to reference the element in CSS, use the Inspect tool of Google Chrome.
For further details on how you can make advanced selections check out:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp

This could come in handy if you have a complex identification methodology employed, or you wish to minimize CSS.